# Story about someone serving a life sentence when their life has been extended indefinitely

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a short story, which I'm pretty sure I read online.  The narrator was sentenced to life in prison, but after sentencing, some sort of nanotechnology was released, infecting everyone and making them immortal.

The narrator (male) is now hundreds (thousands?) of years into a life sentence, and feels like he has been forgotten by the rest of the world.

Note: I saw this similar question, but neither of the stories proposed on [Looking for a short story about a society where when you are sentenced to life in prison, you are kept alive in prison forever](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66867/looking-for-a-short-story-about-a-society-where-when-you-are-sentenced-to-life-I) is what I am looking for.

Comment: +1 for having done your research and looked for possible duplicate questions here on this site.

Comment: You don't recall whether the prisoner was male or female? Do you recall what he/she was in for? murder, treason, forgery, jaywalking?

Comment: Dunno what it is, but the writer shows a lack of research as a "life sentence" is a quantified number in reality and they'd be released in after some number of 120 or less years. (I don't remember the exact number it's between like 80 to 120 from what i remember)... Not important but just commenting...

Comment: @Durakken - I suspect a “life sentence” could easily mean something different in a future society. Beside, seems that it [depends](http://abc11.com/archive/7006724/) on the [state](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081018193412AAqVEOS).

Comment: I am 99 44/100 % certain that I saw that story (I did see it, I'm sure) on "The Twilight Zone", (original series) but could have been "The Outer Limits". It seems like the shows overlapped each other in their strangeness. I think you will that script in the archives or episode lists of one of those weird & wacky series. Regards, -PP-

Comment: @RichardP Are you thinking of the 1996 Outer Limits story "The Sentence" with David Hyde Pierce? In which case I don't think it quite fits.

Comment: @Durakken It actually depends where you are and the time. We get the name 'life sentence' because it used to be just that, is that in some places, and may become so again. The former Prime Ministers of both Canada and the UK both backed the "Life is Life" movements, where those committed to life sentences for first degree murders would be imprisoned for life unless pardoned or the first degree conviction was repealed. (The former Prime Minister of Canada and the present Prime Minister of Canada during the last Parliament both worked towards repealing social benefits from murderers of wives.)

Comment: If it helps, there's a twilight zone (I think) episode, where a woman makes some deal that gets her immortality.. but her husband (lord of the castle) punishes her (mildly, to his thoughts) by locking her in one of the torture chamber items (a cage where you squat over sharp spikes; you can't stand, and exhaustion will cause you to impale yourself) 'for the night' -- then, while she is down there, her betrayal causes the castle to be overrun, and the victor razes it to it's foundation, leaving her trapped below, forever, and immortal, in the torture cage.

Comment: There's a different Twilight Zone where a man makes a deal with the devil for immortality and is later sentenced to life in prison

Comment: @user14111 I believe the prisoner was male.  They didn't mention what they were in for (but it had happened a long time ago)

Comment: I doubt it's the Twilight Zone episode with the man in prison.  He intentionally went to prison to try to get the death sentence, but they gave him life in prison instead.  The episode ended shortly after that; no mention of being left for hundreds of years, or being forgotten.

Comment: It might have been inspired by the Twilight Zone, but it was a short story, told in the first person, not a script.

Comment: The Twilight Zone episode described in previous comments is "Escape Clause", Season 1 Episode 6, originally aired 1959-11-06.

Answer (score 1):

The story you describe sounds similar to [*Habeas Corpus Callosum*](https://strangerthansf.com/reviews/analog-2014-11November.html) by Jay Werkheiser, published in the [November 2014](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23121915-analog-science-fiction-and-fact-november-2014) issue of Analog Science Fiction and Fact.

> A murderer sentenced to life in prison might win a reprieve. Since his conviction, life extension procedures have made humans essentially immortal. Therefore, his life sentence is now effectively either an infinite incarceration (if he's given the treatment) or a death sentence (if the treatment is denied), neither of which are in the spirit of his original sentence.

In this story, I don't think the prisoner is actually hundreds or thousands of years old, so you may be thinking of a another story.

As of now (January 2020) the story is available online at [SciPhiJournal](https://www.sciphijournal.org/index.php/2017/01/20/habeas-corpus-callosum-by-jay-werkheiser/).

Answer (score -3):

I seem to remember a Spider Robinson story, maybe in Melancholy Elephants or Antinomy but I don't have them handy to check, that could be what you meant.